# Windows Form Application using HTML

Tags: c#, windows

I have created a Windows Form Application project in C# with some buttons, text, and other things ...

Is it possible to use HTML, JS, CSS for the UI and to interact with the C# ?

Call a function, modify an object, etc .

Comment: Not so much using Windows Forms... unless you include some kind of Browser control. Have you looked into using UWP?

Comment: For your reference https://www.codeproject.com/articles/990346/using-html-as-ui-elements-in-a-winforms-applicatio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Web browser control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w290k23d(v=vs.110).aspx), which is based on Internet Explorer. It has a COM based API with a managed [wrapper](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171711(v=vs.110).aspx), which allows you to do bi-directional communication. There is also [CefSharp](https://cefsharp.github.io), which allows embedding of Chromium based browsers in Winforms and WPF applications.